# How can I customize each of the taxonomy term pages?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 9

I have a site with Drupal 9. I have created a taxonomy and I want to personalize the terms pages. In Drupal, there is a view for that, but if I change it, I change all the taxonomy term pages.

I want to create a view to customize each page of the terms. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the module TVI for this.

Comment: @Kevin Great, thank you. I will test this